# Object.defineProperty the prop invisible under chrome devtool

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, watch

Well, I ran into question when I'm trying to use the polyfill of `Object.watch` in Chrome. 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/watch
https://gist.github.com/eligrey/384583

The polyfill is pretty a short one, and you can read how it delete the original property and right away define a new property same value but with override getter and setter.

The problem is, if you use this polyfill and watch on o.p:

```
var o = { p: 1 };
o.watch("p", function (id, oldval, newval) {
  console.log( "o." + id + " changed from " + oldval + " to " + newval );
  return newval;
});
```

After that you check the object `o` under chrome devtool. Bang! Object `o` is empty now! Actually it still has the property `p`, type `o.p` you'll find `o.p = 1`.

My question is, why the property is invisible under Chrome developer tools object property list?

Note: if you don't know/interested in `Object.watch`, you may still be able to help me on this question, as long as you understand `Object.defineProperty` well.

---

Edit: it turns out that it's nothing like I thought that it creates a new property, only overriding its getter and setter. 
Quoting from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty
"Property descriptors present in objects come in two main flavors: data descriptors and accessor descriptors. A data descriptor is a property that has a value, which may or may not be writable. An accessor descriptor is a property described by a getter-setter pair of functions."

So it looks like the polyfill changes the target property from a "data property" to a "accessor property". I assume that the only way to polyfill this?

Comment: It's not invisible, it is changed to a `getter` and `setter` by the `watch` polyfill. That's how `watch` knows when it is modified.

Comment: Òk, if you read the code you will see it makes a copy, deletes the old property and re-adds that property as a getter and setter with the old value. -> changed

Comment: I can see it. [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/FUJ5h/)

Comment: @Xotic750 Hmm.. I thought it creates a new property, only overriding its getter and setter. But no it's nothing like I thought..

Comment: as a library developer I wonder if there is a way I can make my objects look "normal" in the chrome web inspector

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My question is, why the property is invisible under Chrome developer tools object property list?

Answer is: it is visible, but now it is a getter and setter.

```
Object {}
get p: function () {
set p: function (val) {
__proto__: Object
```

<kbd>[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/FUJ5h/)</kbd>

If though, you are asking why you can't see it's value: that's because the value is now private and can only be read by using the getter.

```
console.log(o.p);
```

Update: Read [Mutator method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutator_method)

> **Mutator method**
>
> From Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia
>
> In computer science, a mutator
>   method is a method used to control changes to a
>   variable. They are also widely known as '''setter''' methods. Often a
>   setter is accompanied by a '''getter''' (also known as an accessor),
>   which returns the value of the private member variable. The mutator
>   method, sometimes called a "setter", is most often used in
>   object-oriented programming, in keeping with the principle of
>   encapsulation. According to this principle, member variables of a
>   class are made private to hide and protect them from other code, and
>   can only be modified by a public member function (the mutator method),
>   which takes the desired new value as a parameter, optionally validates
>   it, and modifies the private member variable.

Consider this example

```
function MyClass() {
    var privateVar = 0;

    this.getPrivate = function () {
        return privateVar;
    }

    this.setPrivate = function (value) {
        privateVar = value;
    }
}

var newObject = new MyClass();

console.log(newObject);

console.log(newObject.getPrivate());
```

Output

```
MyClass {getPrivate: function, setPrivate: function}
getPrivate: function () {
setPrivate: function (value) {
__proto__: MyClass

0
```

On <kbd>[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/zgg5z/)</kbd>

You can view the object and see the public methods `getPrivate` and `setPrivate` (similar too real getters and setters created by `Object.defineProperty`), but you can't see the value of the member variable `privateVariable`. You can only view the value by calling the `getPrivate` public method.

Comment: Thx but honestly, I haven't accept this as the answer, because this really doesn't explain much. Yes, there comes a pair of get/set p to replace the 'property p'. I can assume there are many others who think this observed fact is a bit confusing. I had hoped this question can lead to some explanation so I/we can understand Object.defineProperty more hence understand javascript object properties more.

Comment: @kakacii it answered your question, _"Why the property is invisible?"_; _"It's not."_ Consider rephrasing your question.

Comment: @Xotic750 I see your update. I appreciate your effort to help people, but no offence, either you tend to oversimplify things or you are a js master. I just think "Property descriptors present in objects come in two main flavors: data descriptors and accessor descriptors", this is counter-intuitive and seemingly not a good design. Maybe it's just me.

Comment: @canon if you say so.. I have make the only answer the accepted answer.